# 'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied' after running a python script using a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, runtime-error, file-permissions, autostart

I'm using a bat file to run a python script at boot. Manually, running the script through CMD causes no problems. But, executing it using the bat file creates the permission error, where the script is supposed to take a screenshot and save it.

I've tried using different modules for taking the picture, thinking this is the problem - but it didn't help. I also gave administrator privileges, but this did not help as well.

Here is the bat file:

```
"C:\Users\name\python.exe" "C:\Users\name\run.py" pause
```

these are the problematic lines in the python code:

```
image = ImageGrab.grab()
image.save('C:\\full\\path\\to\\screen.png')
```

And the error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Path\\to\\screen.png
```

The expectation is for the code to run error-less through the batch file, as it is executed manually.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it still fail when you specify the full path to screen.png? I have a theory that the file is getting saved to different places based on how the script is called, especially if you're using Task Scheduler to make the script run at boot.

Comment: @SomethingDark Thank you for the reply.Yes it does. And i am using windows registry to run the bat file at boot. Maybe it is worth noting that these lines are within a loop.

Comment: In this case it is not an issue with NTFS permissions. It is a file sharing access permissions issue. Another process or perhaps even same Python script has most likely the PNG file opened when the Python script tries to open it too. You could use the free Sysinternals (Microsoft) tools [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) or [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to find out which process has the PNG file opened resulting in file access denied by Windows. Has PNG file the read-only file attribute set?

Comment: @Mofi there is indeed a parallel process, searchProtocolHost.exe which accesses the file before the script.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this same issue with Task Scheduler.  I tried / and \ and other options but still had issues.  What worked for me was to cd into the directory withhin the bat file.

Previously, my .bat file was simply:

```
python "C:\path\to\some\directory\run.py"
```

I updated my .bat file to:

```
cd "C:\path\to\some\directory"
python run.py
```

Hopefully this helps others that run into this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was changing \ sign to / for the file location in .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to running a batch script via task scheduler.
I solved the issue by click on "Run with highest privileges" option; Action --> Create Task --> General --> "Run with highest privileges"